# Determining bound of LP knowing dual variables

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

I have a simple LP of the form:

\begin{align*}
\text{maximize } & c^Tx\\
\text{s.t. }     &A_1x = b_1 \\
&A_2x \le b_2 \\
&x\ge0
\end{align*}

with $x\in R^n$, $A_1 \in R^{m\times n}$, $A_2 \in R^{l\times n}$, $b_1 \in R^{m}$, and $b_2 \geq 0 \in R^{l}$.

Let's introduce the dual variables relative to the constraints defined above.

- $y_1$ for the equality constraint
- $y_2$ for the inequality constraint

Assume now that we know the values of the following: $A_1$, $b_1$, $A_2$, $y_1^*$, $(c^Tx)^*$ (we don't know $x^*$ but only the optimal cost value).

How can we determine $b2$ such that the optimal solution to the corresponding primal and dual problems have value $(c^Tx)^*$ and dual variable $y_1^*$, respectively?

Here what I have done so far. First, I have written the associated dual problem:

\begin{align*}
\text{minimize  } & \lambda_1^Tb_1 + \lambda_2^Tb_2\\
\text{s.t. }     &A_1^T\lambda_1 + A_2^T\lambda_2 >= c \\
&\lambda_2\ge0
\end{align*}

Here the problem is that both $\lambda_2$ as well as $b_2$ are, in our case, unknown (optimization variables). However, we know that:

- both variables in the bilinear term $\lambda_2^Tb_2$ are non-negative
- the term $b_2$ appears only in the bilinear term mentioned above
- strong duality holds so that the optimal cost of the dual is equal to the optimal of the primal (that we know)

These conditions allow us (do they?) to introduce the auxilary variable z_i=$\lambda_{2, i}b_{2, i} \leq \lambda_{2, i}b_{i, max}$ $\forall i \in R^l$. I have a natural bound, $b_{i, max}$, for each component of $b_2$. Putting all of this together we obtain:

\begin{align*}
\text{minimize  } & 1^Tz + \lambda_1^Tb_1\\
\text{s.t. }     & 1^Tz + \lambda_1^Tb_1 >= (c^Tx)^* \\
 &A_1^T\lambda_1 + A_2^T\lambda_2 >= c \\
&\lambda_2\ge0 \\
& z \leq \lambda_2b_{max}
\end{align*}

If all I have done is correct this would allow us to solve in $z$, $\lambda_2$ and the obtain each component $b_{2, i}$ as:

$$ b_{2, i} = z_i/\lambda_{2, i}$$

where $b_{2, i}$ will be undetermined whenever $\lambda_{2, i} = 0$.

I have implemented this but the solution seems completely off. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your condition $$A_2 x  \leq b_2$$ is equivalent to $A_2 x + y = b_2$, $y\geq 0$

Comment: What you want is to solve your problem by adding a variable (this is called dualization I believe) so change your second inequality with my equality and then you get $(x_0,y_0)$, your solution is $x_0$? I don't even get what you are looking for there is no question in your post

Comment: No unfortunately that's not what I am after. First I don't know the value for $b_2$ which means that also using your equality I don't know how to solve the LP. More precisely, I am interested in determining $b_2$ that is compatible with the observed $C^Tx^*$ and $y_1^*$

Comment: @JulesBesson You seem to be confusing slack variables with dual variables.

Comment: I recommend explicitly writing out the dual problem.

Comment: @luk767 This is not how this works. Please share all the details in your possession and what you have been doing.